# Jersey consume JSON on POST

Tags: java, jquery, json, rest, jersey

I am trying to send some json data via jquery POST to a jersey REST service in my local machine.

In my server side, I have Jersey method to consume this JSON which is POSTed.

```
@Path("/question")
public class QuestionAPI {


    private final static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(HelloWorldApi.class .getName());

     @POST
     @Path("/askquestion")
     @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
     @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
     public TQARequest askquestion(TQARequest tqaRequest, @Context HttpServletRequest request) {

         LOGGER.info("Inside-->askquestion-->TQARequest"+tqaRequest.getQuestion());

         return tqaRequest;

     }


}
```

I am wrapping the json data in request. So that in server , I can get all data sent in request in that wrapper class. My wrapper class for request is

```
public class TQARequest {

    private Question question;

    public Question getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }

    public void setQuestion(Question question) {
        this.question = question;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "TQARequest [question=" + question + "]";
    }



}
```

The Question pojo class

```
public class Question {

    @Id
    private Long questionID;

    private String questionText;

    private long createdOn;

    private String questionURL;

    private String questionTrackingURL;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Question [questionID=" + questionID + ", questionText="
                + questionText + ", createdOn=" + createdOn + ", questionURL="
                + questionURL + ", questionTrackingURL=" + questionTrackingURL
                + "]";
    }

    public Question(String questionText, long createdOn, String questionURL,
            String questionTrackingURL) {
        super();
        this.questionText = questionText;
        this.createdOn = createdOn;
        this.questionURL = questionURL;
        this.questionTrackingURL = questionTrackingURL;
    }

    public Long getQuestionID() {
        return questionID;
    }

    public void setQuestionID(Long questionID) {
        this.questionID = questionID;
    }

    public String getQuestionText() {
        return questionText;
    }

    public void setQuestionText(String questionText) {
        this.questionText = questionText;
    }

    public long getCreatedOn() {
        return createdOn;
    }

    public void setCreatedOn(long createdOn) {
        this.createdOn = createdOn;
    }

    public String getQuestionURL() {
        return questionURL;
    }

    public void setQuestionURL(String questionURL) {
        this.questionURL = questionURL;
    }

    public String getQuestionTrackingURL() {
        return questionTrackingURL;
    }

    public void setQuestionTrackingURL(String questionTrackingURL) {
        this.questionTrackingURL = questionTrackingURL;
    }

    public Question(){

    }


}
```

Whenever I make a request from the jquery as shown below ,

```
 function askQuestion(){


        $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
              url: "/api/question/askquestion",
              data: 
               JSON.stringify({
                   "tqaRequest" : {
                          "question" : {
                             "createdOn" : "sfddsf",
                             "questionText" : "fsdfsd",
                             "questionTrackingURL" : "http://www.google.com",
                             "questionURL" : "ssdf"
                          }
                       }
                    }

                     ),
              dataType: "json",
              success: function(response){

                  console.log(response);

              }
            });  

    }
```

**I get this error in the console :**

```
WARNING: /api/question/askquestion: org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "tqaRequest" (Class com.netsquid.tqa.entity.TQARequest), not marked as ignorable
 at [Source: org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser$Input@899e3e; line: 1, column: 16] (through reference chain: com.netsquid.tqa.entity.TQARequest["tqaRequest"])
```

I can fix this by sending Question json from jquery and accepting question parameter in the method. **But I need to wrap all the jquery requests in TQARequest and accept all the request as TQARequest and then extract the question object from it. How do I do this ?**

My POJO mapping in web.xml is:

```
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe you can simplify the JSON document as follows:

```
{
    "question" : {
        "createdOn" : "sfddsf",
        "questionText" : "fsdfsd",
        "questionTrackingURL" : "http://www.google.com",
        "questionURL" : "ssdf"
    }
}
```

It's still a "tqaRequest" object in this form.

If you want to support a list of questions, your JSON might look like this (JSON arrays go inside square brackets):

```
{
    "questions" : [
        {
            "createdOn" : "date 1",
            "questionText" : "question 1",
            "questionTrackingURL" : "http://www.google.com",
            "questionURL" : "question 1 url"
        },
        {
            "createdOn" : "date 2",
            "questionText" : "question 2",
            "questionTrackingURL" : "http://www.google.com",
            "questionURL" : "question 2 url"
        }]
    }
}
```

And you would adjust your TQARequest class to reference:

```
private List<Question> questions;
```

instead of

```
private Question question;
```

Comment: But what if , I need one more level of JSON ? for ex : 

{
 "q1":{
      "question" : {
        "createdOn" : "sfddsf",
        "questionText" : "fsdfsd",
        "questionTrackingURL" : "http://www.google.com",
        "questionURL" : "ssdf"
     }
   }
}

Comment: If you add another level, you'll need to mirror this in your Java object model. So in that case you would have a TQARequest object, wrapping a Q1 object, wrapping a Question object. Can you be more specific, though, about what you want to do? Do you want to take in a list of questions?

Comment: Yes , I need to take in a list of questions all wrapped in TQARequest object from my html page in json.

Answer (score 5):

Hope this solves the problem.

```
@POST
@Path("/askquestion")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public TQARequest askquestion(String jsonRequest){       
         TQARequest tqaRequest = MapperUtil
                                  .readAsObjectOf(TQARequest.class, jsonRequest);
    }
```

**MapperUtil.java**

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();

 public static <T> T readAsObjectOf(Class<T> clazz, String value)
          throws MYPException {
 try {
      return MAPPER.readValue(value, clazz);
      } catch (Exception e) {
      LOGGER.error("{}, {}", e.getMessage(), e.fillInStackTrace());
 }
}
```

Comment: @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)  , but the argument is String. So should I consume MediaType.PLAINTEXT ?  , But this will break my REST spec , I prefer the producer and consumer should be in JSON.

Comment: not sure, I my case it produces `JSON` but I didn't specify `@Consumes`, it works fine for me. Did you try with your existing set-up? ie., with `@Consumes` as `JSON` and argument as String.

Comment: I think, the question was not about how to map json-string to object manually, but rather about how to configure Jersey to map to TQARequest automatically.